# How to add a message that says "Website Loading" when a website takes a long time to load on slow internet connections?

Tags: javascript, web, joomla2.5

Sometimes when our customer is on a slow internet connection, it seems to take forever to load our website. I wanted to know if there is a way to show a spinning wheel while the website loads and the spinning wheel disappears once the website is fully loaded. The website is built using Joomla.

We have already implemented something simple using the onLoad function which displays the content of the website only after its loaded fully and until that time shows a animated GIF and a line to text that says "Please wait while the website loads".

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: using ajax if you actually want to wait till the server executes your query.Or else as a dummy you could use jquery

Comment: Don't.  The browser handles this for you.  Don't add to the load time with things like this.  Besides, don't you think those folks with slow internet connections know they have slow internet connections?  There is no need to tell them anything.

Comment: @Brad cant he use ajax?I have used it before

Comment: @User211 Sure he can, but why would you want to?  It's far better to get the content out there on the page then hack crap like that in for your primary content.  It's much faster to just load something than it is to load the loader to load something.

Comment: I guess your suggestion seems better..since its slow internet connection.

Comment: @User211—for what? While a browser is loading the resources for a page it already gives the user feedback until loading has finished (e.g. spinning icon on tab, load completion indicator in address field or status bar, etc.). You can already detect whether loading has finished as the *load* event won't occur until it has (or checking [readyState](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-xmlhttprequest-readystate) via the [readystatechange event](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#events)).

Comment: Thank you Brad, RobG and User211 thank you for your comments. Very useful. My intention was to indicate that the website "on the way" so that the visitor is reassured that the website has started loading.

Answer (score 1):

This would surely help to resolve your problem.
**["Please wait... loading..." message?](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=169017&view=previous)**

Comment: Plus `window.onload = deleteLoadingMessage;`. :-)

Comment: @signumsol—I think there was an element of sarcasm in that answer…

Comment: @RobG . oh ok Sorry I did not get it at that time.